# Microsoft translator widget not translating contents loaded dynamically(e.g. using ajax call)

Tags: language-translation, ajax-request

We are trying to understand different language translation options for our mvc application.

We checked how Microsoft translator widget working. As per their document, we have added embedded script to our pages. It loaded translate button. it is translating content to selected language.  But then after if any content loaded dynamically (e.g. making ajax call and loaded some partials in the page), it is not automatically convert to language. We need to again reset and re-select the language to convert again.

Note: In case of google translate widget, they are converting automatically all dynamic content after loading them.

We want same functionality using Microsoft translator widget. Is there any way to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, Microsoft no longer supports the Translator widget and the available solution is to integrate the Translator Text API in your website or application. To do this you will need to subscribe to the Microsoft Translator Text API. Visit the Getting Started page at http://www.aka.ms/TranslatorGettingStarted and you will find the steps.